# Multiple lxml trees in one document

Tags: lxml

I understand each XML tree is created by parsing a document that starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

In some of XML files I encounter, there are multiple chunks sitting within the same  `.xml` file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
  </ethnicity>
</data>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
  </ethnicity>
</data>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
  </ethnicity>
</data>
```

In this example, there are 3 chunks, which are typically 3 lxml trees. But for big files with unknown number of chunks, how to parse in this situation and what would be the root node? The intention is to deal with each chunk as a separate tree.

Comment: A file with "XML chunks" is not itself an XML file (since there is no common root element). You would have to create a separate XML document for each chunk and parse them individually.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for responding. This happens when I read Kafka stream. The data is published in XML format. And it is streaming. From the ```consumer``` side (i.e. the reader), if I read the stream into a text file, I get the example above. But if I don't read it out as a text file first, I don't even know how to parse the stream. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: But if the final answer is that there is no way to do that with ```lxml```, that is good to know, too.

Comment: The `csplit` Unix command can split up a text file based on a pattern. You could use that to create 3 proper XML files from the input in the question.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/csplit